# Use Front Camera and Back Camera into single video

Tags: android, camera, mediarecorder

I am working with a project where I want to record a video using both front- and back-camera simultaneously using Camera2.
In this case, I want to have one camera as full screen and then the other one as a small thumbnail in the corner.

I know how to open both cameras simultaneously and I know how to record a video from a single camera.
My guess is that I need to some how create my own `SurfaceView` and then write both of the camera buffers on top of that View and send that to the `MediaRecorder`.

It's really hard to find any quality answers for these types of questions and was hoping that someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

No, you must arrange the two frames that come from the cameras in a composite image and pass it to the MediaCodec. This must be repeated for each pair of frames received from the two sources.

Comment: Yea, that is what I thought. How do people do this in an efficient way?
I could always make and rgb of the Yuv images and then write them directly to the surface canvas for the MediaRecorder but there must really be a better way than that right?

Comment: If you want to go RGB, have a look at [grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/f3c8c3dee60153f471312e21acac8b3a3cddd7dc/src/com/android/grafika/TextureMovieEncoder.java) sample code. Usually, I prefer to work in YUV colorspace.

Comment: I would like to go YUV also, it would probably be more effiecient, but how do you for example write such images on a surface in a controllable fasion? Got any examples?

Comment: You don't need to write these images on surface; you construct them in memory. The preview surfaces or textures work as usual, while your processing merges the frames independent of preview.

Comment: Fine, but how do I construct the image from the two feeds?

Comment: Usually you do it pixel by pixel, or row by row if you are lucky

Comment: I will probably prepare a code snippet for that in October